# Problems for setting up my own simulation environment in gazebo fuerte

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated ROS to Fuerte few days ago. And here were some problems I got when using Gazebo.

1.

My first question is that I can't rotate the object in gazebo. For example:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2k99bigrh2db7p/gazebo_1.png

When I clicked on the pr2, I could drag the square to move it. But I couldn't find the ring around it, which I could drag and rotate the model.

2.

My second question is that I can't put a bowl on the table:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iud6rxfx8j5dxd/gazebo_2.png

I first inserted table.model, and then inserted bowl.model. And I tried to put it on the table. The bowl would either fly away or fall down to the ground. Here I say "fall down" doesn't mean that it will go through the table top. In fact, it just reappeared on the ground and started swinging, as if it fell from some where above. In addition, the swing would not stop, may also be some problem for the physics engine.

3.

My last question is that I can't spawn model using the launch files in gazebo_world package:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9mliqxausz1hfg/gazebo_3.png

When I do the following:

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds coffee_cup.launch
```

I can't see the object. I tried to select it from the side column "Models". I see where it is... And the I tried to move it. However, when I pulled it up, it just floated in the air and never dropped down.

Appreciation for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34561/problems-for-setting-up-my-own-simulation-environment-in-gazebo-fuerte/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

About point 3 : Spawning is done manually with :

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf (or -gazebo) -file coffee_cup.urdf (or .urdf) -model table -x xcoord -y ycoord -z zcoord
```

According to [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls#Adding_an_STL_Mesh_Object_in_Simulation)

In launch file, I use :

```
<node pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" name="addingdetails9" args="-gazebo -file $(find gazebo_worlds)/objects/object102.model -model objet102 -x 1.0 -y -1.0 -z 0.6" />
```

with args being rosrun args, that is working on electric. I didn't have a look to changes with Fuerte but I don't think it would change a lot.

About pt 2 :
You can spawn directly cup on the table if setting right the coordinates. Nodes starting order is not predictable, so you can spawn your cup 2-3 meters high to be sure that table has spawned on a flat floor before the cup comes on the table (if an object is already there when you spawn another one, it makes usually both fly - without any actuators ;) !). It's probably not the best solution but it fixes more or less the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0